# Rank non-contiguous dates with a monthly reset

Tags: powerbi, dax

With reference to the below sample data, I have a table in Power BI that currently only contains the `Bus_Day` column. I am attempting to add the `MTD` column (in red) that counts the monthly cumulative number of `Bus_Day`. The rows highlighted in yellow are reflective of the requirement that the `MTD Day` column should reset to 1 for the first `Bus_Day` per month.

My challenge is the `Bus_Day` column does not contain contiguous dates, so using `DATEDIFF` is not an option.

[image]

Comment: In the future, please provide actual sample data instead of an image. If the data can be copy-pasted into Power BI you are much more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problem where you want to label non-contiguous dates, `RANKX` is your go-to unless you can solve it further upstream in your stack.

Here is a DAX column solution that adds a calculated column according to your specifications:

```
MTD Day = 
VAR _yr = YEAR ( [Bus_Day] ) 
VAR _mth = MONTH ( 'Table'[Bus_Day] )
RETURN
    RANKX ( 
        FILTER (
            'Table' , 
            YEAR ( [Bus_Day] ) = _yr 
            && MONTH ( [Bus_Day] ) = _mth
        ), 
        [Bus_Day] , , ASC 
    )
```

You can also calculate this using a measure, this formula does the trick with your sample data:

```
MTD Day Measure = 
VAR _day = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Bus_Day] )
VAR _tbl = 
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table' ) , 
        YEAR ( 'Table'[Bus_Day] ) = YEAR ( _day ) 
        && MONTH ( 'Table'[Bus_Day] ) = MONTH ( _day )
    )
RETURN
    RANKX ( 
        _tbl, 
        CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Bus_Day] ) ) , , ASC 
    )
```

Result:

[image]